# Defining the control and treatment groups in a spatial RDD

Tags: r, spatial, regression-discontinuity

I would like to evaluate the effect of a policy change that happened in 2014 in a region called R.

Before the year of the treatment, each city of R was classified into 4 zones called A, B, C, D, classified by order of "emergency", A being the best zone and D being the worst zone. After the year of the treatment, this zoning system was kept but some cities' ranking worsened. Most of the changes were from A to B, B to C, or C to D, or no changes, but never the other way around.

I have individual-level panel data. Suppose I would like to study the effect of being in a city whose ranking exogenously changed on individuals' socioeconomic outcome. Conceptually speaking, I would like to know what's the difference between :

(1) Studying the effect of an individual who stayed in the same zone before and after the treatment but whose zone's ranking got worse (Ex : City1 went from B to C)

(2) Studying the effect of an individual who moved from a bad zone in pre-treatment (City1, C) to a good one (City2, B) after the treatment

In both cases, if the individual's socioeconomic outcome went better, can we say that it is the result of the policy?

I'm actually struggling to define precisely my control group and my treatment group, knowing that individuals are mobile over time. I would appreciate any help or reference on the subject!